# Why does Tkinter make a new window for my button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

Im trying to add a button into my window, but it makes a new window for the button, how can I add it to the same window where I have a background on?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk

top = Tk()

C = Canvas(top, bg ="blue", height=1920, width=1080)
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/plapl/Desktop/ching.jpg")
background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()


root = Tk()

myButton = Button(root, text = "Add a task")
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have created a new instance for Tk().
change it to this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk

top = Tk()

C = Canvas(top, bg ="blue", height=1920, width=1080)
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/plapl/Desktop/ching.jpg")
background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()

myButton = Button(top, text = "Add a task")
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It gets rid of the second window but it doesn't add a button for some reason

Comment: Try adding command argument in the button. for example:
myButton = Button(top, text = "Add a task", command=quit)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have **2** Tk() objects, which means that 2 windows are created. To solve this, change the line: `background_label = Label(top, image=filename)` to this: `background_label = Label(root, image=filename)`.

Then, you can get rid of this line: `top = Tk()` because it isn't needed anymore.